# use _app in subpath ? nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

question please!,

my folder structure :

```
src
  /pages
    /order
      _app.js
      index.js
```

with this structure it's work until I want to use "next-redux-wrapper", I got a error in index.js type : "Could not find "store" in the context..."

and if I put app.js and index.js root to pages (without subpath order so) i can use redux easily, what is the problem with my initial folder src, it's impossible to use this structure if I want to use redux ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is `"it's impossible to use this structure if I want to use redux ?"`?

tl;dr: The answer is `Yes, it is possible`.

I'm also using `src` folder to place all of my codes, and it works fine with redux.
I (can only) guess (since you just provide a snippet of code), the problem with your app is you didn't specify `src` folder somewhere (in import function or else where that cause redux not working).

While error that you mention `Could not find "store" in the context..` means that you didn't put your store in your application's context so when the app was looking for that, it couldn't find the store.. or the way you call your store isn't correct.